# How to find subgroups, is my method correct , and if so what is another method for doing so?

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

Say we have the Group $(\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_4,+)$, this group has the following elements;

$\{(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)\}$ and so is a group of order 12. Therefore ( I believe) that the subgroups are found by looking for groups of order 1,2,3,4,6,12.

We can also note that $|\langle g \rangle|=o(g)$(i.e the order of the element g)

$\therefore  \langle(0,1)\rangle:=\{(0,1)(0,2)(0,3),(0,0)\}$ is a subgroup as $o((0,1))=4$ and $|\langle(0,1)\rangle|=4$

$\langle(2,3)\rangle:=\{(2,3),(1,2),(0,1),(2,0),(1,3),(0,2),(2,1),(1,0),(0,3),(2,2)(1,1)(0,0)\}$ has order 12 and so is also a subgroup.

When I was going though the list of elements in $\Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_4$ It seemed like they all generated a group of order 1,2,3,4,6 or 12, Is this true ?

Also if my method for computing subgroups is correct, is there any other ways to  find subgroups apart from using this generator technique ?

Comment: Your group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, see the links on MSE, or [this homework solution](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/Math504/Homework/section11.pdf).

Comment: Use `$\langle\rangle$` for $\langle\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\gcd(3,4)=1$, we have $\Bbb Z_3\times \Bbb Z_4\cong \Bbb Z_{12}$ (by the Chinese Remainder Theorem), so the group is cyclic and so, hence, all its subgroups are cyclic; it is then a matter of finding which elements of $\Bbb Z_{12}$ generate a proper subgroup then seeing which of these is distinct from any others, a significantly easier task (in my opinion).